# Unable to retrieve Data according to email from Firebase

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new with firebase and was trying to show data according to the email id to recycler view but recycler view is showing the row of it.
This is my onCreate method.

```
     mDatabase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("user_project_status");
        //mDatabase.child(email);
        mDatabase.keepSynced(true);
        projects_token=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.selected_projects);

        projects_token.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        projects_token.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
 LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(Status.this);
        //Creating a view to get the dialog box
        View confirmDialog = li.inflate(R.layout.pageloader, null);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) confirmDialog.findViewById(R.id.mImageLoading);
        Animation animation1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Status.this,
                R.anim.flip_anim);
        imageView.setAnimation(animation1);
        //Creating an alert dialog builder
        alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Status.this);

        //Adding our dialog box to the view of alert dialog
        alert.setView(confirmDialog);
      //  alert.setCancelable(false);
        alertDialog = alert.create();
        alert.setCancelable(false);
        //Displaying the alert dialog
        alertDialog.show();
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Status_getter,StatusViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Status_getter, StatusViewHolder>(Status_getter.class,R.layout.status_row,StatusViewHolder.class,mDatabase.equalTo("email",email)) {

            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(StatusViewHolder viewHolder, Status_getter model, int position) {
                final String post_key=getRef(position).getKey();
                if(model.getEmail().equals(email)) {
                    viewHolder.setProject_name(model.getProject_name());
                    viewHolder.setToken_no(model.getToken_no());
                    alertDialog.dismiss();
                }else{

                    alertDialog.dismiss();
                }

                viewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        Intent i=new Intent(Status.this,Selected_Status.class);
                        i.putExtra("status_id",post_key);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                });
            }

        };


        projects_token.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
```

And this is my status_getter class through which I am setting my data. It is called with name model

```
   String token_no,email,progress_dialog,progress_message,project_name,project_description,software_type;
    public Status_getter(){

    }
    public Status_getter(String token_no, String email, String progress_dialog, String progress_message, String project_name, String project_description, String software_type) {
        this.token_no = token_no;
        this.email = email;
        this.progress_dialog = progress_dialog;
        this.progress_message = progress_message;
        this.project_name = project_name;
        this.project_description = project_description;
        this.software_type = software_type;
    }

    public String getToken_no() {
        return token_no;
    }

    public void setToken_no(String token_no) {
        this.token_no = token_no;
    }

    public String getSoftware_type() {
        return software_type;
    }

    public void setSoftware_type(String software_type) {
        this.software_type = software_type;
    }

    public String getProject_description() {
        return project_description;
    }

    public void setProject_description(String project_description) {
        this.project_description = project_description;
    }

    public String getProject_name() {
        return project_name;
    }

    public void setProject_name(String project_name) {
        this.project_name = project_name;
    }

    public String getProgress_message() {
        return progress_message;
    }

    public void setProgress_message(String progress_message) {
        this.progress_message = progress_message;
    }

    public String getProgress_dialog() {
        return progress_dialog;
    }

    public void setProgress_dialog(String progress_dialog) {
        this.progress_dialog = progress_dialog;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
```

I have create a xml row namely "Status_row" which makes a custom Recyclerview.

Value stored in my database is like this.

[image: 1]

Comment: I don't understand. What are you getting? And what are you expecting instead?

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes I want to show token_no and project name in firebase recycler view according to email id. I have saved email id in sharedpref and I am fetching that. Now if some otherlogs in he can see both